# window.onload doesn't load the body before script runs

Tags: javascript, html

I have been having trouble writing javascript in my HTML documents without having the script run before the page fully loads. I have stripped the code down to very basic to try to eliminate everything I may be doing incorrectly. I want to have the page load before the function `init()` runs and am using `window.onload` to do this. However, the alert from the function runs before the page loads. This happens whether I put the script in the head or the body. What am I don't wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Green Planet</h1>
    <p id="greenplanet">All is well</p>

    <h1>Red Planet</h1>
    <p >Nothing to report</p>

    <h1 >Blue Planet</h1>
    <p >All systems A-OK</p>

    <script>
        function init() {
            var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
            planet.innerText = "Red Alert: hit by phaser fire!";
            planet.setAttribute("class","redtext");
            alert("it initialized");
        }
        window.onload=init;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code shown [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sBD2b1X1yKTuZtj9e8o3?p=preview)

Comment: What makes you think the page hasn't loaded? Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: I am using Chrome and the alert shows and the webpage is white before the rest of the page loads.

Comment: try removing the alert. Works fine for me in multiple browsers

Comment: The alert is the way of showing the function is firing before the page is loading. How do I get the page to fully load before the function fires?

Comment: It ***is*** loading before the function fires. That is how `onload` works.

Comment: Charlietfl, thank you for your help. I ought to have been specific that the problem was only on Chrome and Safari but on other browsers it seemed to work. Thanks for taking time to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the page to fully *render* before the function is executed? If so, you could wrap the body of your function in a call to `window.setTimeout()`. For example, this will fully render the page for one second before executing your function:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Green Planet</h1>
    <p id="greenplanet">All is well</p>

    <h1>Red Planet</h1>
    <p >Nothing to report</p>

    <h1 >Blue Planet</h1>
    <p >All systems A-OK</p>

    <script>
        function init() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var planet = document.getElementById("greenplanet");
                planet.innerText = "Red Alert: hit by phaser fire!";
                planet.setAttribute("class","redtext");
                alert("it initialized");
            }, 1000);
        }
        window.onload=init;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alien (aka fellow Ridley Scott Fan), Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. My challenges were with Chrome and Safari--Firefox seemed to load correctly with my original code. Your solution fixed my problem. Thanks for taking the time to help out!

Comment: @Clairol: I'm glad I could help, and I'm glad you're a Ridley Scott fan too. :) Please accept my answer (click the checkmark) so it will be clear to others that this is the accepted solution.